# Как можно определить что на сайт заходят через curl для третьей стороны

Tags: curl

Я живу в КЗ, и у нас регулярно блокируют доступ к Телеграмм и ютубу, и тут опять не открывается телеграмм я проверяю curl все работает, а через браузер нет. Что за магия

Answer (score 0):

Возможно магия заключается в чтении заголовков, а именно user-agent
Так же можно погуглить что такое DPI и как его обойти

Comment: Хах, я не верю что по user-agent как никак TLS